# Google Data/OAuth/AppEngine/Python - Properly Registering a Web Application

Tags: iphone, python, google-app-engine, oauth, google-data-api

I'm creating a webapp with this combination of tools.  I'm authenticating with App Engine in the following manner:

```
class googleLogin(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    callbackURL = 'http://%s/googleLoginCallback' % getHost()

    #Create a client service
    gdClient = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
    gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(gdClient)
    gdClient.SetOAuthInputParameters(gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, 
                                     _GoogleConsumerKey, 
                                     consumer_secret=_GoogleConsumerSecret)

    #Get a Request Token        
    requestToken = gdClient.FetchOAuthRequestToken(scopes=_GoogleDataScope,
                                                   extra_parameters={'xoauth_displayname': APP_NAME})

    #Persist token secret
    self.session = Session()
    self.session[TOKENSECRETKEY]        = requestToken.secret

    gdClient.auto_set_current_token = True
    gdClient.SetOAuthToken(requestToken)
    authUrl = gdClient.GenerateOAuthAuthorizationURL(callback_url=callbackURL)
    self.redirect(authUrl)
```

I authenticated my domain with Google at https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomain, entering a target URL and am using the given Consumer Key/Secret.  For instance, if my domain was 'juno.appspot.com', I am using http://juno.appspot.com as the target url path prefix.

The process is working; however, Google presents this message to the user in a yellow security box:

> "The application that directed you
>   here claims to be 'xxxxxx'.  We are
>   unable to verify this claim as the
>   application runs on your computer, as
>   opposed to a website.  We recommend
>   that you deny access unless you trust
>   the application."

I don't think I should be getting this error, since my server is getting the request token and creating the authorization URL.  Does anyone have any insight on how to get rid of this warning?

Google's domain registration has an option to upload a certificate, but I shouldn't need to do that because I'm using OAuth with the HMAC_SHA1 signature method.

Also, not that it should matter, but I'm doing all this through a UIWebView on the iPhone.  I'm specifically trying to do all authentication server-side to avoid exposing my Consumer Key/Secret.

Thank you for any tips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

The culprit is this line from above:

```
extra_parameters={'xoauth_displayname': APP_NAME})
```

Setting this value for a registered application intentionally triggers a warning to users, as indicated by the Google documentation:

> **xoauth_displayname**:
>
> (optional) String identifying the
> application. This string is displayed
> to end users on Google's authorization
> confirmation page. For registered
> applications, the value of this
> parameter overrides the name set
> during registration and ***also triggers
> a message to the user that the
> identity can't be verified.*** For
> unregistered applications, this
> parameter enables them to specify an
> application name, In the case of
> unregistered applications, if this
> parameter is not set, Google
> identifies the application using the
> URL value of oauth_callback; if
> neither parameter is set, Google uses
> the string "anonymous".

Removing this line no longer allows me to use a 'nice' name in place of the domain, but it gets rid of that annoying yellow box :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly where the issue may be in your code, but I've got a one page [oauth/appengine/gdata example](http://pastebin.com/SmLZNVnj) which may at least set you in the right direction. Have you tried to navigate to the site directly from the iPhone/desktop browser to see what message is delivered?

Hope it helps.

Alternatively, is it possibly to do with the user agent the UIWebView sets?

Comment: Thanks for the tips oli.  I managed to solve it eventually, but it was useful to look at your code sample.  It's irritating how many ways Google has set up to try to handle this problem, instead of having one definitive way.  I'd almost rather construct the http calls myself rather than deal with their convoluted API.